# Custom Functions not working for IIS hosted Office Excel add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We deployed Batching Custom functions project into IIS as hosted application. Task-pane is working fine with API. But when trying to invoke as custom functions facing issue

> Error in loading custom functions

at the bottom of add-in. We developed using webpack.config.js but little confused when deploying on IIS for exact server running. So do we need to use express js to run separate port or directly shall we run only enough webpack.config.js file? Kindly confirm on this deployment process.
Also Taskpane related API's are able to fetch successfully but only facing issue with custom functions related API.

Answer (score 0):

You may can check if custom function related files can be seen in your website hosted by IIS. You can have the url information in manifest file.

Comment: Those thing already i have tested and i am able to see like you said. But when i trying to invoke in Excel again it is trying to open as seperate add-in in new custom tab with above mentioned error.

Comment: We are using the scratch project from below link                  https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Excel-custom-functions/Batching. Everything working fine in local system. When trying as hosted site facing the issue in loading Custom functions.

Comment: Only thing we added below piece of code in web pack config to work custom functions in desktop version to achieve API POST call with header application/json                                                               
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'https://....',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        },        
    },
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: 3000
    },

Comment: With those changes in web pack config.cs custom functions are working in local Desktop version and facing only in hosted application. Also kindly confirm about web pack config and let me know if anything need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check whether you could access the JSON file by browsing to  http:///custom-function.json? Would you please also check whether the mime type is correct? If the mime type is not correct, you may need to update the web.config, such as

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

By the way, to make it work for Excel online, you also need to enable CORS access to the custom-function.json

Comment: @Zhu, I am able to browse and download json file with IIS hosted url ex: https://localhost:3000/functions.json. where do check mime type in VS code project?

Comment: Hi, Today am able to resolve that "Error in loading custom functions" by changing correct url for function.ts files in manifest since those only are under dist folder. Now facing the issue as  "#VALUE!" when invoking the function. But same are working in local VS code. This issue only in IIS hosted site. Kindly help to trouble shoot further.